# Получение данных из JSON в js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, npm

Задача такова. Есть функция, которая читает JSON файл, и выдаёт/возвращает его содержимое. При сборке проекта, JSON читается сразу, и полученные данные записываются в уже готовый js. Мне же нужно, чтобы после сборки функция каждый раз заново обращалась за данными к JSON файлу (то есть компилировала файл JSON тоже, не переводя его данные сразу в js). Как такое можно реализовать? Надеюсь понятно выразился...

Вот функция:

```
    const text = require('./test.json');

    export function displayText(text) {
      return text.map((x, i) => {
        switch (x[0]) {
          case 'p':
            return <p>{x[1]}</p>;
          case 'hr':
            return <hr />;
          case 'br':
            return <br />;
          default:
            return null;
        }
      });
    }
```

И примерно так выглядит файл json:

```
[
    ["p", "some text"],
    ["br"],
    ["p", "some text"],
    ["p", "some text"],
    ["hr"]
]
```

Comment: прикрепи реализацию текущей функции. И для слова "билдинг" есть русскоязычный вариант -- сборка.

Comment: За "сборку" меньше платят, а за "билдинг" больше... неужели это еще не все знают?

Comment: @Mikhail Прикрепил. Исправил

Comment: Я обычно использую require для js файла. А в js файле `var content = (бывший JSON-файл)`. Если это заменить на `function content() { return (бывший JSON-файл)}` то должно заработать. Не знаю, поможет ли тебе такой способ. Еще можно получать JSON через web-запрос к серверу. Или к nginx.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin Заменил, не помогло. "Еще можно получать JSON через web-запрос к серверу", какая разница откуда он получает, он всё равно будет при сборке читать и сразу в js файл закидывать...